# Weird issue when trying to update Pi3 (on Stretch)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-stretch, apt

Logs below, do I have to update to Buster?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for pi:
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python3-systemd
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files libfaad2
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 219 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf base-files armhf 9.9+rpi1+deb9u11
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libfaad2 armhf 2.8.0~cvs20161113-1+deb9u2
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_9.9+rpi1+deb9u11_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/f/faad2/libfaad2_2.8.0~cvs20161113-1+deb9u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did this only happen once?  Sometimes a server become unavailable temporarily. Usually if I try again later it works.

Comment: hey @Brick yup, but been the same way for last 8 hours, never had this issue in 4 years.

Comment: looking at `http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/b/base-files` there is no `base-files_9.9+rpi1+deb9u11_armhf.deb` ... so that mirror is out of date

Comment: @JaromandaX so what should I do?

Comment: @JaromandaX just changed it to http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian seems ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup it is down in ireland (not the server though, theres just some missing files).
Other people are having issues, including me;
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=252335&p=1539782

Edit: You can change the apt source/ repo by and fix this issue by:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then you edit the first line by adding a # at the beginning.
Add the the end of the line:

```
deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Your file should look like this:

```
    #deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-$
    # Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
 #deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib $
    deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Then Ctrl-x to save + Y
Then :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

The issue should now be fixed